Alguien sabe como crear un codigo en Lua para Roblox Studio para que cuando 2 objetos colisionen, se haga entre ellos una rope?
Necesito que alguien me ayude a crear un codigo en Lua para Roblox Studio que haga de que cuando 2 partes se choquen, se haga una rope constraint entre esas 2 partes. Logre hacer todo esto:
local enganche1 = workspace["Chasis Disel"].Tren["Parte Principal"].Acopladores["Acoplador 1"]["Enganche 1"]

local enganche2 = workspace["Chasis Disel"].Tren["Parte Principal"].Acopladores["Acoplador 2"]["Enganche 2"]

function acoplar()

(Aca es donde nose como hacer la funcion para que esto suceda)

end

Necesito de que cuando enganche 1 haga contacto con enganche 2, se haga una cuerda entre enganche 1 y enganche 2. Gracias.

si alguna de las respuesta te ha servido podes marcarla como resuelta, eso te dara al menos 2 puntos de reputacion que te seran utiles en un futuro. saludos.

No soy experto en lua ni en roblox-studio, el que se dedica a eso es mi hijo de 9 años, le he preguntado y me dice que tienes que detectar la colisión.
Me paso este código que dice ser el que el implemento:
-- Referencias a los objetos en el Workspace
local enganche1 = workspace["Chasis Disel"].Tren["Parte Principal"].Acopladores["Acoplador 1"]["Enganche 1"]
local enganche2 = workspace["Chasis Disel"].Tren["Parte Principal"].Acopladores["Acoplador 2"]["Enganche 2"]

-- Función para crear una RopeConstraint entre dos partes
function acoplar(part1, part2)
    -- Crear una nueva RopeConstraint
    local ropeConstraint = Instance.new("RopeConstraint")

    -- Configurar las propiedades del RopeConstraint
    ropeConstraint.Attachment0 = Instance.new("Attachment", part1)
    ropeConstraint.Attachment1 = Instance.new("Attachment", part2)

    -- Establecer el radio de la cuerda (opcional)
    ropeConstraint.Thickness = 0.2

    -- Establecer la longitud máxima de la cuerda (opcional)
    ropeConstraint.Length = (part1.Position - part2.Position).magnitude

    -- Ajustar otras propiedades según sea necesario
    ropeConstraint.Visible = true -- Hacer la cuerda visible
    ropeConstraint.Color = BrickColor.new("Bright yellow")

    -- Parentar el RopeConstraint a una de las partes (o a un contenedor en el Workspace)
    ropeConstraint.Parent = part1
end

-- Conectar la función a los eventos de Touched de ambas partes
enganche1.Touched:Connect(function(hit)
    if hit == enganche2 then
        acoplar(enganche1, enganche2)
    end
end)

enganche2.Touched:Connect(function(hit)
    if hit == enganche1 then
        acoplar(enganche2, enganche1)
    end
end)

Entonces preguntandole como funciona esto me dice que:

Referencias a los objetos: Definimos las referencias a enganche1 y enganche2 en el Workspace. similar a lo que ya tienes

Función acoplar: Creamos una función que toma dos partes (part1 y part2) y crea un RopeConstraint entre ellas. Configuramos los Attachments de la cuerda y sus propiedades opcionales como grosor y longitud. Luego, el RopeConstraint se parenta a una de las partes.

Detectar colisiones: Usamos el evento Touched de enganche1 y enganche2 para detectar cuando una parte toca la otra. Si enganche1 toca enganche2, llamamos a la función acoplar y viceversa.


Otras consideraciones importantes:
Puedes ajustar las propiedades del RopeConstraint según tus necesidades, como la visibilidad, el color, el grosor, etc.
Asegúrate de que enganche1 y enganche2 tengan la propiedad CanCollide establecida en true para que puedan detectar colisiones.
El resultado que debes de esperar es algo asi:

Tengo que darle el crédito a mi hijo por tan buena respuesta.
